# Сохранение файлов webpack по разным папкам?

Tags: webpack

В [доках webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/) имеется:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    search: './src/search.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  }
};
```

Получается, что в entry можно указать путь до любого файла в src.

Вопрос: как правильно на настоящий момент в webpack 4 указывать в output пути до разных папок, например сохранить app.js в /dist/app/, а search.js в /dist/search/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению - никак. `You can only have one output path.`, но можно использовать несколько конфигов и экспортировать массив с этими конфигами:

```
// webpack.config.js

const { join } = require('path');

const appConfig = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: join(__dirname, 'dist/app')
    }
};

const searchConfig = {
    entry: './src/search.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: join(__dirname, 'dist/search')
    }
};

const common = {
    context: __dirname,

    module: {
        rules: [...]
    }
};

module.exports = [{
    ...common,
    ...appConfig
}, {
    ...common,
    ...searchConfig
}];
```